# Is there a concept of GUI based file copy like Windows?

Tags: permissions, nautilus, filemanager, sharing, drag-and-drop

I'm new to **Linux** and **Ubuntu** and come from a **Windows** background.

I need to copy gigabytes of files from a **Drobo network share** to a new **secondary drive** in the **Ubuntu** box. I have created a folder inside the **media** folder called **data01** and mounted the new drive to it. I have can see the **Drobo network share** in the network section  if I just use **File Manager** from the side bar.

If I try to copy the files from the Drobo using **Nautilus** opened from the side bar I get **permission** or **operation** errors. If I try using **Nautilus** (with **sudo** prefix via terminal) then I can't see the **Drobo**.

***Is there an equivalent process*** in **Ubuntu** which **mirrors** opening two "Windows Explorer" windows side by side and **dragging and dropping** to copy the folders and files in **Windows** to copy them? One which will not keep giving me loads of permission errors?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you limit yourself with all these restrictions? What you do should be done with a terminal by setting the correct permissions by the admin and a copy command to copy the data.  This is what the terminal is intended for. Use Linux where it is strong in ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind: There's nothing wrong with using Nautilus to copy data. But of course you need write permissions on the target

Comment: @Deb: What file system (FAT, NTFS, ext4, ...) do you have on the target drive?

Comment: @FlorianDiesch there is if the answer is "use sudo nautilus".

Comment: @Rinzwind - Why would I not want to use a GUI? Rich user interfaces have been around for decades, so why is it that Linux is so antiquated that everything that a "super user" might want to do has to be done by command line? The last time I went near Linux (BEOS?) was about ten or fifteen years ago, and I had really hoped it had moved into the 21st century allowing everyday jobs to be done without opening a terminal session. I guess I was wrong!

Comment: @FlorianDiesch - As far as I know the Drobo has a proprietary file system, but it gets served as Fat32 for consumption by Windows or Mac OS machines.

Comment: @Dib Here we disagree. Command line is not "antiquated"; it is a feature. And the *best one* ever invented. You need to discern 2 roles: admin and user. admin tasks works best on command line. user tasks on a gui. But for the user to be able to copy "anywhere" (mind the quotes) the admin needs to setup the system accordingly.

Comment: @Rinzwind - Yes we will have to disagree. My day job is to write user interfaces which allow users to perform the actions which I (and others in my team) get fed up performing manually. So my focus is always give the user an GUI.

I dont consider copying files as a "super user" task. On  a Windows machine I can copy what ever files I want to wherever I want. I don't need to have this hidden away from me for some super user to perform the action if they think it is safe enough. If I accidentally remove a system file, then that is my fault. I don't need the OS saying I cant!

Comment: This said, I can see why Linux is used on server boxes where limited access is paramount, but I am thinking it may have been a mistake to use it as a media server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `gksudo nautilus` in the box that appears, you get a GUI file manager running as root.
The <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> brings up a box allowing you to ask for any command directly, without a terminal - very useful at times. I mostly use it when I want `kill`

This nautilus will allow you do the job - but be careful not do do anything else in it as all the normal checks are off! Close it when done. You can open a second window to simplify your copy job.

Comment: Please don't run GUI applications with `sudo`, for which it is unfit. Use `gksudo` instead to avoid various issues.

Comment: Gksudo has been removed as standard and pkexec is coming in;  however pkexec isn't complete (and doesn't work for this command) so I avoided it for now.

Comment: @MarkWilliams - So this looks like it will work and using this technique I an open two windows next to each other.  The problem I have now is my network is unbrowsable. If I however right click on *Files* in the side bar and choose to open a new window I can see my network assets, but I am back to having no permissions. Is there a way to open *Nautilus* with *ALT* + *F2* and *gksudo* and still have access to my network?

Comment: I notice in the NETWORK area of Files my drobo has an address in the format of afp://myDroboUsername@MyDroboName.local/MyFoldername/     However if I copy this into the filemanager running as ROOT it throws a wobbler as seems to try to resolve this relative to /home..

I need to get access outside of home and back to my network. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hold the fort! I don't know how I have managed it, but now using a combination of your suggestion here and some other forum suggestions including renaming and creating a new **/local** folder in the **/usr** folder I now appear to have permission to copy folders and files from my network location to my second drive. I'm sorry but I cant describe what I did for others as it was a one or more than one thing of a number of things. Anyway thank you all for your help. I will mark this as answer as it got me on the right track!

Comment: Particularly this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=801597&page=6&p=7942187#post7942187